# Issue with encapsulating fields in a dynamic SQL string builder

Tags: sql, vba, vb.net

I am trying to create a dynamic SQL string builder for my application and am having some issues with encapsulating the fieldnames with brackets.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub BuildDynamicSQL( _
                         FieldsArray() As String, _
                         ByVal TableName As String)                            

    ' Declarations ->
    Dim strSQL As String: strSQL = vbNullString
    Dim Field As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    ' Validate fields array ->
    If IsEmpty(FieldsArray) Then Exit Sub

    ' Construct SQL using Fields array ->
    strSQL = "SELECT "
    For Each Field In FieldsArray
        If i = 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL + "[" + Field + "]"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL + "," + "[" + Field + "]"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next

    strSQL = strSQL + " FROM " + TableName

End Sub
```

When I run this code with more than one field in my FieldsArray, I keep getting the following output with unnecessary leading spaces.

```
SELECT [log_id],[ log_description],[ create_user],[ create_date_time] FROM activity_log
```

Has anyone got any idea how I can get this to work as expected?

Many thanks.

Comment: Change `strSQL = strSQL + "[" + Field + "]"` to `strSQL = strSQL + "[" + Trim(Field) + "]"`

Comment: I would humbly suggest putting the table name as the first argument/parameter then using a paramarray for an unknown number of fields. Also, a function returning a string may be a better method.

Comment: `strSQL = "select [" & Join(FieldsArray, "],[") & "] from " & TableName` if you fix the issue with spaces in your array values.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. Just needed to add the "," back into it and it worked. This sub is actually setting the rowsource property of a form control hence the reason it is not a function with string return value. I also have optional Where and OrderBy parameters as well hence the reason I am not using a paramarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalized example of a function accepting a paramarray argument and returning a string.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = buildMySql("mytable")
    Debug.Print sql

    sql = buildMySql("mytable", "fld1", "fld2", "fld3", "fld4")
    Debug.Print sql
End Sub

Function buildMySql(tbl As String, ParamArray flds()) As String
    Dim str As String, f As Long

    If IsMissing(flds) Then
        str = "select * from [" & tbl & "];"
    Else
        str = "select "
        For f = LBound(flds) To UBound(flds)
            str = str & "[" & flds(f) & "]" & IIf(f < UBound(flds), Chr(44), vbNullString)
        Next f
        str = str & " from [" & tbl & "];"
    End If

    buildMySql = str
End Function

'results
select * from [mytable];
select [fld1],[fld2],[fld3],[fld4] from [mytable];
```

Comment: Jeeped - not sure if you got to see my last message but this sub I am writing is actually setting the rowsource property of a form control hence the reason it is not a function with string return value. I also have optional Where and OrderBy parameters as well hence the reason I am not using a paramarray.

Comment: Yeah, I caught the comments after I wrote and tested the code then drafted the reply. Maybe you should revise the original question because as it is currently, this is a valid reply.